# how to put checkbox inside select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I get checkbox within select tag,and also I need to get values of select box when I select

I am using ajax to append data to select box

```
success: function(data) 
{
      var toAppend = '';
      $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(i,o)
      {
          toAppend += '<option value='+o.invoice_id+'>'+ o.invoice_number+'</option>';
      });
      $('#client_invoices').append(toAppend);
}

//html
<select name="" id="client_invoices" class="form-control simple-select">
</select>
```

Can anyone help me on that please

Comment: do you want to add checkbox inside an `option`

Comment: You cannot.  A <select> tag cannot contain a checkbox.  In order to put a checkbox in a "select" you will have to use a plugin that replicates the look and feel of a select, but is not an actual select.  Two possibilities are jQuery UI selectmenu https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ and bootstrap dropdowns https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: @brk yes I want  to add checkbox inside an option